# The string "--" is not permitted, java project

Tags: java, xml, string, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cure for ‘The string “--” is not permitted within comments.’ exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155940/cure-for-the-string-is-not-permitted-within-comments-exception)

I have a Java project to parse and edit XML files.
When I try to run the project I get the following log message:

```
The string "--" is not permitted within comments.
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The string "--" is not permitted within comments.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:246)
...
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: and similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324821/nested-comments-in-xml

Answer (score 8):

Without further knowing your code:

There error is as you were told. Somewhere in your XML sheet, you have a comment, which includes a `--` in it. For example something like this:

```
<root>
  <!-- my comment with -- in it -->
</root>
```

This is not a well formed XML. Within a comment `--` is not allowed. The parser will have problems to detect the end of the comment then.

Comment: May you can explain why it's difficult for the parser? I mean "-->" defines the end of the comment. So why is the parser not just ignoring the "--" and looking further?

Comment: DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   docFactory.setIgnoringComments(true);
   docFactory.setValidating(false);   
   DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
   doc = docBuilder.parse(file);

Comment: @Timo +1 for comment, I just searched and found that they kept it like this to remain compatible with SGML

Comment: @Timo: Because its specified that way for compatibility with SGML: http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-comments

Comment: there is no way to resolve this?