# How does one pass codeception commands that start with "--" via ant to Jenkins?

Tags: xml, jenkins, ant, codeception

Building my first ant build.xml file to have Jenkins run Codeception tests and I'm receiving an error `"--" is not permitted within comments`

I know from reading elsewhere on stackoverflow that xml doesn't allow this.
[Cure for 'The string "--" is not permitted within comments.' exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155940/cure-for-the-string-is-not-permitted-within-comments-exception)

The conundrum is that several Codeception commands start with --: --xml, --html, --env, etc.

```
 <target name="View" description="test for single aaView page">
        <exec executable="${codecept}" failonerror="true">
            <arg value="run" />
            <arg value="tests/acceptance/aaViewCept.php" />
            <arg value="--xml" />
            <arg value="${basedir}/browser/${browser}/tests/_output/report.xml "/>
            <arg value="--env" />
            <arg value="${browser}" />
        </exec>
    </target>
```

The kicker is that if I remove `failonerror="true"` Jenkins runs the test just fine.  I'm experimenting with putting it in as Jenkins shows a passing build with failing test if I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parts `=--"` are not valid XML.

Use `<arg value="--xml"/>` and `<arg value="--env" />`

The value attribute of the arg element defines arguments passed to the executable and the `--` is part of those arguments.

But if you put a XML comment around the `<target>` element the XML parser will indeed complain because now the `--` are not allowed within the comment.

Comment: argh.  Sorry.  That cut and paste was after a weird and uneducated attempt to remove the -- from the quotes to see if it would help.  Will update original now.

Comment: @CosetteN do you have an XML comment starting with `<!--` and ending with `-->` around the `target ` element?

Comment: I do not have <!--  --> surrounding this code, but I do have it around other code.  Removing it is allowing the test to run.  Thank you.

Comment: I was expecting comments to work more like they do in PHP.  I appreciate the link, thank you!